# Jsoup, Selecting element is not working

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jsoup

Jsoup the selecting element selects the div not, But the hole jsoup is working but the selecting element not.

```
TextView text;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tb);
    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new doit().execute();
        }
    });

}

public class doit extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

    String words;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.blablabla.com/").get();
            Element newsHeadlines = doc.body().getElementById("div#content");
            System.out.println(newsHeadlines);
            words = doc.text();

        }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        text.setText(words);

    }
}
```

Comment: `getElementById` doesn't use CSS query notation, it just takes value of ID you ware searching. So assuming IDs are unique like they should be, you can use `getElementById("content")`, but if you want to use CSS query then you need `select"div#content")` method.

Comment: not working :(.

Comment: Then you also have other problems. I just pointed one with jsoup query. Are you sure you are even getting proper response from serwer? Could you print content of `doc` to see if it really contains div with `id="content"`? Many pages simply sends main template as response with JavaScript code which should fill it with data later, but jsoup doesn't support JS.

Comment: BTW `words = doc.text();` takes text from whole site, you probably wanted `words = newsHeadlines.text();`

Comment: THAAAAAANk YOU :DDDDDD i love you xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your source to this

```
public class doit extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    String words = "";
    try {

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.blablabla.com/").get();
        Element newsHeadlines = doc.body().getElementById("div#content");
        System.out.println(newsHeadlines);
        words = doc.text();

    }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

    return words;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String words) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    text.setText(words);

}
```

}

Comment: can you get the string ?

Comment: I am not saying you are wrong, but posting only code without any explanation is not very helpful.

Comment: You are working with different threads, one is your main Thread the second is backgroundThread ,,, that's why your string resource will always  be null

Comment: ooppsss,,, change super.onPostExecute(aVoid); to super.onPostExecute(words);

Comment: can you send me yourApp.apk ,,, or zip file ,,, I'll help you

Comment: srry i helped my father wait 5 minutes then i gave you the code

Comment: here is my mail,,, adana942@mail.ru

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Element newsHeadlines = doc.select("div#content");
```